# Link inside created DIV cause the div removed on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, mouseout

Here is my code:

```
var tagDes = document.createElement('DIV');
                    tagDes.className = 'tagDes';
                    tagDes.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;'+
                                    'background:#282828;'+
                                    'color:#fff;'+
                                    'padding:10px;'+
                                    'top:'+(posX+hei)+'px;'+
                                    'left:'+(posY+wid)+'px;'+
                                    'font-size:10pt;';
                    tagDes.onmouseout = function(){
                                        $(this).remove();
                                    };
                    $('#main-container').append(tagDes);
                    $('.tagDes').append(array[5]+'<a class="tagMenu">sdsdssds</a>');
```

posX, posY, hei, wid is reffering to an element for positioning. array[5] is a string.
I want to hover for a `li` and create div that contain link(`tagMenu` class) inside(looks like `title` attribute). But when I hover the link inside that div, the div will `remove()`. What I looking for is when I hover the link the div still visible and it will removed from page when I `mouseout` from it. Any suggestion? Please help me.

Comment: Are posX and posY the wrong way round?

Comment: No, its give a correct value. It will return `li`'s position so the div can approaching beside it

Comment: I meant: `'top:'+(posX+hei)+'px;'` uses the horizontal position with the height, and `'left:'+(posY+wid)+'px;'` uses the vertical position with the width. So are posX and posY the wrong way round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
 tagDes.onmouseout = function(e){
 if (e.toElement.parentNode == this || e.toElement == this) {
       return;
     }
   $(this).remove();
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to bind `onmouseout` event to inner link element. Then the code can be like this (I made use of more jQuery to simplify it):

```
var $tagDes = $('<div class="tagDes"></div>').css({
    background: '#282828',
    color: '#fff',
    padding: '10px',
    top: (posX + hei) + 'px',
    left: (posY + wid) + 'px',
    fontSize: '10pt'
})
.append(array[5] + '<a class="tagMenu">sdsdssds</a>')
.appendTo('#main-container');

$tagDes.on('mouseleave', function() {
    $tagDes.remove();
});
```

Comment: Woa...it's so close to my deal. But now, the div is not `remove` onmouseout pal.

Comment: It will be removed on link mouseout. Do you want it to remove on div mouseout itself?

Comment: Yes, but it was so close to my request. I'll vote up you pal.

Comment: Oh, I see, so you need `mouseleave` event rather then `mouseout`. See updated code. Anyways, glad you found a solution working for you!